# LINQ where query

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Tables => 
Groups
Subgroups

I need to select ONLY groups from Groups table that have been checked via(checkboxes) which contain SubgroupId

Statement below works but it also selects groups that have empty subgroups. please help

```
var test =
    this.MailingGroupRepository.List().ToList()
        .Cast<MailingGroup>()
        .Select(e => new campaignSegmentCondition
        {
            extra = string.Empty, 
            field = "interests-" + e.GroupingId, 
            op = "all",
            value = string.Join(",", 
                updateRow.MailingSubgroup
                    .Where(r => r.MailingGroupId == e.MailingGroupId)
                    .Select(p => p.Name))
        }).ToList<campaignSegmentCondition>();
```

Comment: You should provide a bit more context (for instance, what is `updateRow`? What does the type `MailingGroup` look like?), otherwise it's hard to give relevant guidance.

Comment: You use the linq-to-sql tag in your question, but what does this LINQ query has to do with LINQ to SQL? As far as I can see, we're talking about LINQ to Objects here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, then there is a very easy solution. Try this:

```
var test =
    this.MailingGroupRepository.List().ToList()
        .Cast<MailingGroup>()
        .Where(e => updateRow.MailingSubgroup
                    .Any(r => r.MailingGroupId == e.MailingGroupId))
        .Select(e => new campaignSegmentCondition
        {
            extra = string.Empty, 
            field = "interests-" + e.GroupingId, 
            op = "all",
            value = string.Join(",", 
                updateRow.MailingSubgroup
                    .Where(r => r.MailingGroupId == e.MailingGroupId)
                    .Select(p => p.Name))
        }).ToList<campaignSegmentCondition>();
```

Note the inclusion of the following code:

```
        .Where(e => updateRow.MailingSubgroup
                    .Any(r => r.MailingGroupId == e.MailingGroupId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if a mailing subgroup is empty or not in you where clause? -

```
updateRow.MailingSubgroup
   .Where(r => !r.IsEmpty && r.MailingGroupId == e.MailingGroupId)
```

if there is no `IsEmpty` property you can also check something like `r.Items.Count  > 0` if possible.